# How to get all possible pairs from an 4x4 Array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

Let's say I have an 2x2 Array.

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
```

And I want to get all pairs possible.

```
[1, 2] [1, 3] [1, 4] [2, 3] [2, 4] [3, 4]
```

And I do not want reversed pairs like `[2, 1]`.

Has anyone a good solution for this problem?

Comment: Your description/example doesn't make sense.

Comment: Two nested loops sound promising, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will actually need three nested loops, or to convert your 2d list to 1d list and then to get your **Permutations**:

```
List<List<int>> My2DList = new List<List<int>>() { new List<int>(){ 1, 2 }, new List<int>(){ 3, 4 } }; // your initial 2d list
List<int> My1DList = My2DList.Cast<int>().ToList(); // convert to 1d list
List<List<int>> Permutations = new List<List<int>>(); // prepare a container

for (int i = 0; i < My1DList.Count; i++)
    for(int j = i; j < My1DList.Count; j++)
        Permutations.Add(new List<int>() { My1DList[i], My1DList[j] }); // add your permutations
```

Comment: Oh wow the solution with the 1D Array is genius.. But how can i solve this with 3 Loops. The first 2 Loops loop over the array but what does the third one?

Comment: Third array is needed to iterate rows of the original 2d array. The routine would be similar but you will need to keep track of which slot you are on in order to `Add` it to the resutl `list`. Glad we were able to help :) Please accept / upvote the answer if it was helpful

Comment: I upvoted your answer. But i do not have enough reputation ;_;